# How to show live preview in a small popup of linked page on mouse over on link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

How to show live preview in a small popup of linked page on mouse over on link ?

like this

http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/03/

but live preview

Comment: By live preview do you mean a video? You can put anything in an inline pop-up like that (object, HTML5 video tag, img, etc). You could perhaps have something server-side where it takes a link via GET and returns a thumbnail pic of that link, then include that image onmouseover.

Comment: @JitendraVyas The link seems to be broken now.

Answer (score 55):

You can use an iframe to display a preview of the page on mouseover:

```css
.box{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}

a:hover + .box,.box:hover{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
This live preview for <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/">Wikipedia</a>
  <div class="box">
    <iframe src="https://en.wikipedia.org/" width = "500px" height = "500px">
    </iframe>
  </div> 
remains open on mouseover.
```

Here's an example with multiple live previews:

```css
.box{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}

a:hover + .box,.box:hover{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
Live previews for <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/">Wikipedia</a>
  <div class="box">
     <iframe src="https://en.wikipedia.org/" width = "500px" height = "500px">
     </iframe>
  </div> 
and <a href="https://www.jquery.com/">JQuery</a>
  <div class="box">
     <iframe src="https://www.jquery.com/" width = "500px" height = "500px">
     </iframe>
  </div> 
will appear when these links are moused over.
```

Comment: Great solution. My one query would be; can you make it so that the iframe that appears when you hover over the link stays visible if you move your mouse over the page that is being shown? In [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcdqt/867/) I have modified your example with how I'd like it laid out, but it would be ideal if, when the page appears, you could move your mouse over it and it stays visible (so you could select text, for instance, without having to navigate to the page). Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Luke I have fixed this issue: see the updated version of my answer.

Comment: is there any fix for IE, i am using IE 11. rest browsers are fine. In IE the .box div is not stayed display on hover itself

Comment: this is a very smart solution, kudos.

Comment: Please note that a webserver can be configured to deny preview in iframe.  If server sends response header X-Frame-Options DENY browser will not display other website in iframe. Example, http://google.com.

Comment: you kinda have a small problem if you are doing anything cross-site ya know, youd have to make an extension to do it, like from within the browser itself  (like firefox) -- you could make a iframe contain a web browser instance (just the page, not the menus, etc) and then set it's link to the desired page. This is of course less than ideal and might require the user to download an extension -- not sure what the limitations of xul are over-the-net. Guess what?? this's also what 'popup' windows originally were for back in the day, ads ruined it for us, thanks alot ads.doubleclick.net!! (sarcasm)

Comment: Is there a way to slightly delay the appearance of the iframe (e.g., 2 seconds) upon the mouseover?

Answer (score 14):

You can display a live preview of a link using javascript using the code below.

```html
<embed src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp" width="60" height="40" />
<p id="p1"><a href="http://cnet.com">Cnet</a></p>
<p id="p2"><a href="http://codegena.com">Codegena</a></p>
<p id="p3"><a href="http://apple.com">Apple</a></p>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://codegena.com/assets/css/image-preview-for-link.css" rel="stylesheet">     
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
                $('#p1 a').miniPreview({ prefetch: 'pageload' });
                $('#p2 a').miniPreview({ prefetch: 'parenthover' });
                $('#p3 a').miniPreview({ prefetch: 'none' });
            });
  </script> <script src="http://codegena.com/assets/js/image-preview-for-link.js"></script>
```

Learn more about it at [Codegena](http://codegena.com/image-link-preview-on-hover/)

```
id="p1" - Fetch image preview on page load.
id="p2" - Fetch preview on hover.
id="p3" - Fetch preview image each time you hover.
```

Comment: I implemented this script on a website. It's great but I have issues importing FB pages

Comment: 6 years later working great

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use a website thumbnail/link preview service [LinkPeek](https://linkpeek.com) (even happens to show a screenshot of StackOverflow as a demo right now), [URL2PNG](https://www.url2png.com), [Browshot](http://browshot.com), [Websnapr](http://websnapr.com), or an [alternative](http://alternativeto.net/software/linkpeek/).

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would avoid iframes and go with an embed tag to create the view in the mouseover box.

```
<embed src="http://www.btf-internet.com" width="600" height="400" />
```

Comment: This is no longer supported by the latest evergreen browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a little plugin to show a iframe window to preview a link.
Still in beta version.
Maybe it fits your case: https://github.com/Fischer-L/previewbox.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

1. Create (or find) a service that renders URLs as preview images
2. Load that image on mouse over and show it
3. If you are obsessive about being live, then use a Timer plug-in for jQuery to reload the image after some time

Of course this isn't actually live.

What would be more sensible is that you could generate preview images for certain URLs e.g. every day or every week and use them. I image that you don't want to do this manually and you don't want to show the users of your service a preview that looks completely different than what the site currently looks like.

Comment: I found this http://thumbnails.iwebtool.com/demo/ in similar question but it's not working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80313/how-do-i-preview-a-url-using-ajax

Answer (score 0):

HTML structure

```
<div id="app">
<div class="box">
    <div class="title">How to preview link with iframe and javascript?</div>
    <div class="note"><small>Note: Click to every link on content below to preview</small></div>
    <div id="content">
        We'll first attach all the events to all the links for which we want to <a href="https://htmlcssdownload.com/">preview</a> with the addEventListener method. In this method we will create elements including the floating frame containing the preview pane, the preview pane off button, the iframe button to load the preview content.
    </div>
    <h3>Preview the link</h3>
    <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

We'll first attach all the events to all the links for which we want to preview with the addEventListener method. In this method we will create elements including the floating frame containing the preview pane, the preview pane off button, the iframe button to load the preview content.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(()=>{
    let content = document.getElementById('content');
    let links = content.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (let index = 0; index < links.length; index++) {
        const element = links[index];
        element.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
            e.preventDefault();
            openDemoLink(e.target.href);
        })
    }

    function openDemoLink(link){

        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.classList.add('preview_frame');
        
        let frame = document.createElement('iframe');
        frame.src = link;
        
        let close = document.createElement('a');
        close.classList.add('close-btn');
        close.innerHTML = "Click here to close the example";
        close.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            div.remove();
        })
        
        div.appendChild(frame);
        div.appendChild(close);
        
        document.getElementById('result').appendChild(div);
    }
})()
```

To see detail at [How to live preview link](https://htmlcssdownload.com/how-to-preview-link-with-iframe-and-javascript)

Comment: Your entire answer seems to be copied verbatim from the linked website. Please indicate that clearly at the beginning of the answer. In fact, it would be nice if you also added an explanation in your own words.