# Display Image on Link Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, hover

I have a number of names in a list like so:

```
<div class="names">
  <ul>
    <li><a href=#name1">name1</a></li>
    <li><a href=#name2">name2</a></li>
    <li><a href=#name3">name3</a></li>
    <li><a href=#name4">name4</a></li>
    <li><a href=#name5">name5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to display next to the cursor an image thumbnail which relates to each name on mouse hover. Is this possible with jquery?

Thanks heaps. Pia

Comment: My knowledge of jquery is almost nothing. Can you point me in the right direction? :) @undefined

Comment: jQuery has a good website http://api.jquery.com you can find all the selectors and methods there.

Comment: Hint: Look for `hover()` in the API

Comment: place image where? what determines image path?

Comment: You can follow this tutorial http://creativeindividual.co.uk/2011/02/create-a-pop-up-div-in-jquery/ and replace the html content in the popover with your image

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show live preview in a small popup of linked page on mouse over on link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117046/how-to-show-live-preview-in-a-small-popup-of-linked-page-on-mouse-over-on-link)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a basic implementation of hover popup:

```
$('.names a').on('mouseenter', function(evt){
    $('.popup').css({left: evt.pageX+30, top: evt.pageY-15}).show();
    $(this).on('mouseleave', function(){
        $('.popup').hide();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CaQUY/

You can alter contents of the popup based on which element is hovered (for example, by using http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/ )

Example of using data attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/CaQUY/1/

Comment: How do i associate a thumbnail with each link using the jquery data attribute? I'm sorry i have no formal training in jquery at all. Can you please update your jsfiddle or show here how to incorporate thumbnails and the data attribute? Thanks heaps for your help. @pckill Pia

Comment: I updated the fiddle, now the popup is showing some images based on the `data` attribute in `<a>` elements.

Comment: Great! One final thing before you go. Is it possible to have anything that looks like this in the html:  `<li><a href="#name1" data-id="images/image_1">name1</a></li>` or would it be `<li><a href="#name1" data-thumbnail-src="images/image_1">name1</a></li>`? And if so what would the jquery look like to reflect this? So the source for each thumbnail is right there in the link. Thanks again for your help. @pckill

Comment: Anything that you put after `data-` in the attribute name represents the identificator by which you retrieve its value. So, if you want to name it `data-thumbnail-src`, you should retrieve its value by using `$(element).data('thumbnail-src')`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a javascript solution to show image thumbnail on hover.

```html
<p id="p1"><a href="https://cnet.com">Cnet</a></p>
<p id="p2"><a href="https://codegena.com">Codegena</a></p>
<p id="p3"><a href="https://apple.com">Apple</a></p>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://codegena.com/assets/css/image-preview-for-link.css" rel="stylesheet">     
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
                $('#p1 a').miniPreview({ prefetch: 'pageload' });
                $('#p2 a').miniPreview({ prefetch: 'parenthover' });
                $('#p3 a').miniPreview({ prefetch: 'none' });
            });
  </script> <script src="https://codegena.com/assets/js/image-preview-for-link.js"></script>
```

If you want to know more on how to use it visit "[Show image thumbnail on hover](http://codegena.com/image-link-preview-on-hover/)"