# Creating preview of a URL entered with php

Tags: javascript, php

```
if ($link == true) {
    // Links
    $link_search = '/\[a\](.*?)\[\/a\]/i';

    if (preg_match_all($link_search, $text, $matches)) {

        foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
            $match_decode = urldecode($match);
            $match_url = $match_decode;

            if (!preg_match("/http\:\/\//", $match_decode)) {
                $match_url = 'http://' . $match_url;
            }

            $str = file_get_contents($match_url);
            preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
            $text = str_replace('[a]' . $match . '[/a]', '<p style="border-style:solid; padding: 6px; border-width: 1px; border-color:#4e5665;"><a href="' . strip_tags($match_url) . '" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><b>' . $title[1] . '</b></a>
                       <br><small>'.$match_url.'</small></p>', $text); 
           }
    }
}
```

The above code shows `<Title>` of the URL and when clicks it, he redirected to the specific URL. What I want to do is add description `<meta>` of the destination below the `<Title>` so that it looks more like a preview of the URL.

What should I do to get the `<meta>` and what and where to add it?

Comment: you could probaly do something in an iframe however not all websites allow their website to be shown in an iframe.

Comment: Use PHPs built-in `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` to extract the content you want.

Comment: Have you checked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117046/how-to-show-live-preview-in-a-small-popup-of-linked-page-on-mouse-over-on-link)?

Comment: Yes I did and it's not helping me. I have succeeded in getting the <title > all  I want to know is how to get meta description

Comment: There's [`get_meta_tags()`](http://us3.php.net/get_meta_Tags).