# HTML URL as a preview instead of text link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So basically what i'm trying to achieve is when i put a link in a specific place, i want it to not show up as a text link but show up as a preview of the website (much like how chrome or firefox does it in the homepage)

I have tried with iframes but some sites do not get rendered in them. Any idea how this could be done?

Comment: I don't believe this can be done reliably as some sites do not allow themselves to be shown in `iframe` elements (through the `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` header - which is the problem you have now). The workaround could be AJAX however you cannot do this client side due to most sites not having CORS enabled so the SOP would block you. Instead you'd need to proxy the request on your server, which is a lot of work for very little real benefit.

Comment: There's no easy way around this issue, because [some sites have been configured to not show in an iframe element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117046/how-to-show-live-preview-in-a-small-popup-of-linked-page-on-mouse-over-on-link#comment49299382_16625709). Your best bet is to use some kind of API to generate static screenshots of the pages, and then display the image. I remember there used to be some kind of plugin that does that, but then that's beyond the purpose of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using web capture service (virtual client that visits website and takes a screenshot and saves it as thumbnail, also parse the website metadata).

Your "special place" should parse the content and send the link to "your capture service" (there are some php/c#/java libraries) or a public web capture service.

Good luck,

example of public api:

http://api.thumbalizr.com/?url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41281928/html-url-as-a-preview-instead-of-text-link&width=160

[image: http://www.thumbalizr.com/]

Comment: ooh, thanks, i will try this, I was going to settle for just using iframes and making a placeholder image for the websites that are not rendered in the iframe :D

Comment: iframe are thing of the past, but a good way to introduce hijackers to your site and redirect scripts. Unless you trust the links :)

Comment: I know, i already had security measure for those but your idea sounds more appealing so I will try it