# How to show live preview in a small popup of linked page on mouse click on link?

Tags: html, css

My question is based on the usage of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117046/how-to-show-live-preview-in-a-small-popup-of-linked-page-on-mouse-over-on-link). I want to use this solution, as presented [here](http://jsbin.com/urarem/4/edit?html,css,output). But instead of on mouse over I would like see the iframe on after I click the link, and be able to close it with another click. Is that possible using only css?

```
This live preview for <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/">Wikipedia</a><div class="box"><iframe src="http://en.wikipedia.org/" width = "500px" height = "500px"></iframe></div> remains open on mouseover.

.box{
display: none;
width: 100%;
}
a:hover + .box,.box:hover{
display: block;
position: relative;
z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with an anchor tag, but you can use the checkbox hack to do that.

```css
.box{
  width: 100%;
}
input, .box {
  display: none;
}
#checkbox:checked + .box {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<label for="checkbox">Click</label>
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox">
<div class="box">
  <iframe src="http://en.wikipedia.org/" width="500px" height="500px"></iframe>
</div>
```

You can show the iframe when you click on an `a` tag using the `:target` pseudo class, but 1) it will jump on the page (without javascript), and 2) you can't close it without clicking on another link on the page and changing the hash in the URL.

```css
.box{
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
.box:target {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<a href="#iframe">click to</a> | <a href="#whatever">click to close</a>
<div class="box" id="iframe">
  <iframe src="http://en.wikipedia.org/" width="500px" height="500px"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: That is really awesome, thank you for your help. But I think I did not explain well. I'm now doing the hover in a cell of a table, and it is annoying because if I move the mouse from one cell to another, lots of things pop out. I could not make your example work inside the table cell. I wanted to use just css to make it simpler, but if you know an easy way to do that with js I would also appreciate.

Comment: Just had this problem to have multiple boxes in a html table, if I name them as #checkbox1, #checkbox2, ..., I can open them individually. Is there a more practical way to do that?