# Preview the page content inside a small section defined as DIV/IFrame

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to show a preview of my page inside a small window placed on the same page. 
The first solution is two follow all steps with the preview section as I follow to build the content of my page   --> In the end, I am going to have a deep copy of the content, and I can do anything with it. I know this will work, but I am looking for any other more elegant solution. 
Like a deep copy of the web content in my preview section. So far, I tried using the jquery load function, or even copy the div content in the new one (Div/Iframe) using .html(), but it creates a copy referenced to the original one and not a deep copy as clone() stands for.

E.g. I have a div section which shows some text and images. And I have some buttons which can change the presentation (size, color etc.) of this section (div). And I want to create a small window, where I am going to show the same content as in div including the changes that clicking a button will occur. It means in this preview window the user sees if it likes to change the presentation, or not.

I would be grateful if you will give me any suggestion regarding this task?

Comment: I think you are looking for something like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117046/how-to-show-live-preview-in-a-small-popup-of-linked-page-on-mouse-over-on-link)

Comment: Something in this direction. The only difference is that I want to preview a div on my page. Where in the preview I will show how a special div will look if the user clicks a Button. Thank you for your suggestion :)