# Convert from css to makestyle material UI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to add an iconButton and display a website preview when the mouse hover the help icon. I found something similar using css but I need to convert that to material UI.
This is the css code to be converted from this post [How to show live preview in a small popup of linked page on mouse over on link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117046/how-to-show-live-preview-in-a-small-popup-of-linked-page-on-mouse-over-on-link)

```
.box{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}

a:hover + .box,.box:hover{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
const HoverText = () => {
        return (
            <div className={classes.box}>
                <iframe src="https://en.wikipedia.org/" width="500px" height="500px">
                </iframe>
            </div>
        );
    };

    return (
        <>
            <IconButton size="large" color="inherit" onClick={() => window.open("https://en.wikipedia.org/", "_blank")}>
                <HelpIcon className={classes.act} />
                <HoverText />
            </IconButton>
        </>
    );
```

Could you please help me to fix this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        box: {
            width: '100%',
            display: 'none'
        },
        act: {
            "&:hover + .box, .box:hover": {
                display: 'block',
                position: 'relative',
                zIndex: 100
            }
        }
    }),
);
```

Im expect to display a preview of a website page when mouse is over the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `$` character when referencing another rule name. I changed a code a bit, use `classes.act` on `IconButton` (the hover effect will be better), and use the following:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() =>
  createStyles({
    box: {
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
      display: "none"
    },
    act: {
      "&:hover $box": {
        display: "block",
        zIndex: 100
      }
    }
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$box` instead of `.box`.

There is no `box` class generated when you compile your code (You can inspect your code and see what it compiles to). So the `.box` class selector does not work because there is no `box` class.

You should use `$` to select another local rule or class within the same stylesheet. [Read more](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested/?v=v10.0.0-alpha.10#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet).

```
"&:hover + $box, $box:hover"
```